# Solr Deduplication use of overWriteDupes flag

Tags: solr

I had a configuration where I had "overwriteDupes"=false. I added few duplicate documents. Result: I got duplicate documents in the index.

When I changed to "overwriteDupes"=true, the duplicate documents started overwriting the older documents.

Question 1: How do I achieve, [add if not there, fail if duplicate is found] i.e. mimic the behaviour of a DB which fails when trying to insert a record which violates some unique constraint. I thought that "overwriteDupes"=false would do that, but apparently not.

Question2: Is there some documentation around overwriteDupes? I have checked the existing Wiki; there is very little explanation of the flag there.

Thanks,

-Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently "overwriteDupes"=false would indeed allow in duplicate documents. The utility of such a setting would be to allow duplicate records but be able to query them later, based on signature field and do whatever one wants to do with them.

The behavior is NOT well documented in the Solr wiki document.

One cannot achieve [add if not there, fail if duplicate is found] in a straight forward manner in Solr.